# How to implement digest authentication in Java?

Tags: java, http-headers, digest-authentication, nonce

I know this is a very broad question but I don't intend to ask you a full implementation (I know there are libraries that will do that for me) I just have some small questions about it.

1. Is the nonce value supposed to go in the http header?
2. how do I read the nonce from the http header in the client side?
3. How do I send back the nonce to the server? Maybe in a hidden field? or will the browser do that for me for each subsequent request?
4. Regarding the client nonce (cnonce) should I send it in the same fashion as any other field or hidden field?
5. How do I get the cnonce back from the server? same way as the nonce?

In my project I'm using servlets to generate the html pages and I have a servlet to handle the http login form.

Comment: See [Digest Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) (and linked RFC's) -- it's all done in headers (e.g. at the "HTTP-level"). Of course the server *may* send a cookie on authentication to use for future requests. Using a tool like [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is very useful to inspect the HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the link although I have seen it before. I found out that I must set the nonce in the www-authentication header but how am I suppose to read it from the client html page? I think I could just put it in a hidden field generated from the servlet but I looks to me that is not the right way, I mean there has to be some way to read the http response header from the client with HTML or Javascript. I have been looking around and I it can be done with php.

Comment: HTTP Auth is a function of the HTTP Protocol and thus handled by the browser -- e.g. with a popup -- *prior* to HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for keeping up with me. It makes sense now, looks like I was getting all wrong. So when I create an httpservletresponse with www-autenticate headers the browser takes care of presenting the popup window and resend the nonce back to server? But what about the cnonce? how can the client side code read the cnonce from the header?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my intention is to create a login form embedded into the home page to set a user session so I think the digest headers should be send to the client when the page loads.

Comment: The cnonce is *randomly generated* by the client (browser) *for each request*. The point of a cnonce (along with the nonce and nc) is to prevent the use of rainbow tables and replay attacks. The client (browser) generate a cnonce and uses nc and qop if the WWW-Authenticate header contains qop. As long as the server sends a valid WWW-Authenticate the client should know how to respond. (Implementing qop is actually more involved because it involves keeping track of nc and nonces to avoid replays.)

Comment: Ok I think you just clear up many things, but what about a regular html form (login)? I mean the browser takes care of all that when the client browser tries to access a protected resource and is challenged with a 401 response but in my case the home page has the login form embedded so the user is not accessing a protected resource and there is no challenge from the server, is there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4698/discussion-between-pst-and-jigzat)

Comment: "Normal form logins" do not use HTTP Authentication at all. Rather they just send the username/password -- hopefully over HTTPS as otherwise they would be "in the clear"! -- as normal form data fields. The authentication tracking in this case is generally handled via cookies and the web-server will re-direct to a "login page" -- a 30x, not a 40x, response -- if the session cookie is missing/invalid/expired. (And yes, authentication -- of either kind -- is applied per resource, or "resource group", however that is defined.)